# git bash questions

Tags: git, bash

i just downloaded msysgit from http://msysgit.github.com/ and am trying to learn how to use it.  i also downloaded a copy of the pro git manual from their wiki. 
In chapter 2 it talks about typing "$ git init" in the project directory to have the system create a .git folder.

i'm just new at unix / linux so you'll have to excuse the simple questions. 
lets say my project folder is located at : 
c:\myapp\abc
and that's where i want to run the git init command

i'm not sure how i can change directories into the project folder. 
when i do an **"ls"** command  from where i'm at, i can tell by the contents in the folder that i'm actually in **C:\Program Files (x86)\Git.**  i've tried "cd /myapp/abc" but it just gives me the message " no such file or directory".
i feel like i'm missing something really basic here.
my prompt when i open git bash is:

$myname@mypcname /

maybe i just need a bash tutorial? 
I've also been playing around with the GIT GUI and i was able to create a new repo in another project folder a  but i'd like to be able to follow the manual, which for now, seems to be working the git bash tool 
thanks.

Comment: definitely make a tiny linux vm (no gui, just a small server) in virtual box on your machine and ssh to it. Msysgit's bash is really good but if you want to get fancy like using multiple streams, it fails. A shared folder between the 2 works great! .. And you'll learn tons about bash.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The "Git Bash" terminal will put the root of each drive in `/<drive-letter>`, so drive `C:\` will be at `/c/`, drive `E:\` will be at `/e/`, etc. Try `cd /c/myapp/abc`.

Answer (score 1):

that should be /mnt/drive-letter in your "Git Bash" terminal

Comment: No, it's not. `/mnt/<drive-letter>` is what you have on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).
In the "Git Bash" terminal, C:\ is /c/, and so on, just as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11617495) says.