# Permission Denied even after chmod 777

Tags: python, cygwin

I have a python script that needs to access 3 files in a folder. When I run the script I get the following:

```
$ python mqtt_pub_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mqtt_pub_test.py", line 10, in <module>
    mqttc.tls_set(my_ca_cert, certfile=my_pri_cert, keyfile=my_key_cert)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 557, in tls_set
    raise IOError(ca_certs+": "+err.strerror)
IOError: C:\Users\<user>\my_phone_certs: Permission denied
```

In an attempt to fix this I ran chmod 777 on everything in that path, even down to the files themselves! 
The variables in mqttc.tls_set are pointing to the folder locations. 
I have no idea why I am still getting permission denied at this point.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using Windows or linux?

Comment: @flazzarini From the file path structure, it's definitely Windows.

Comment: Okey but how do you run `chmod 777` on windows?

Comment: Did you try just calling it like a script? ./mqtt_pub_test.py (with python in the shebang, of course) Edit: didn't notice the environment. it's tagged with linux.

Comment: @flazzarini If I were to take a guess, maybe using cygwin? But it's only a guess to know what's really going on.

Comment: @idjaw if @Lombax uses cygwin the access path should be something like `/cygdrive/c/Users/<user>/my_phone_certs` .

Comment: sorry for the linux tag all. I'm using git bash on windows to make the permission adjustments.

Comment: result from running as ./mqtt_pub_test.py $ ./mqtt_pub_test.py
bash: ./mqtt_pub_test.py: /usr/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: Permission denied

Comment: @Lombax if you are using git bash please have a look at the following stackoverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617433/git-bash-questions

Comment: @Lombox I would really suggest that you would use cygwin instead of git bash, git bash is really just a smaller version of a cygwin installation

Comment: @Lombax how about accepting one of the answers below?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access files which can not be edited:
`mqttc.tls_set(my_ca_cert, certfile=my_pri_cert, keyfile=my_key_cert)`

You could run the script as superuser (`sudo python mqtt_pub_test.py`), if in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in a [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) like environment (which you described in the comments) you should use as file descriptor or let's say file pointer something like `/cygdrive/c/Users/yourusername/phone_certs` (or for git bash for instance `/c/Users/youruser/phone_certs`).

I would really suggest that you would move to [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) entirely as it gives you a more complete linux-like environment on Windows which is very convenient to work with.