# Learning Git - Permission denied while creating a directory

Tags: git, permission-denied

I am absolutely new to Git and the concept of it. I am going through a git immersion here: http://gitimmersion.com/lab_03.html
I am creating a directory called hello by using the command

```
mkdir hello
```

However, I get this error [image]

I'm not sure what to do here.. why am I getting permission denied? Again, sorry if this is a very basic question but I am completely new to this. I have tried googling it but the results seem to be a lot more complicated than what I am just trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to make a directory in the "root" directory, as I see your current working directory is `/`. This probably isn't where you want to create any files or folders, it's just something added by your terminal-emulator to give you a "bash"-like (linux) environment.

To get to one of your Windows drives, for example C, use `cd /c`. You can see where you currently are with `pwd`.

Also see:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11617495/2295034
- https://superuser.com/questions/1192563/where-is-the-git-bash-directory

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. Does it matter where I store my files at? Should it preferably be  in the git folder itself?

Comment: There are many places where you could store your files, but a good place would be in your Windows home directory, which would be something like `/c/Users/johndoe`. You can create your Git directory at that location and then add files within it.

Comment: Argh this is so frustrating I don't understand. My file path I would like to save it at is: C:\Users\Teddy Kim
In git I used cd \c\Users\Teddy Kim and it says too many arguments. If I remove the space between Teddy and Kim it says no directory or file found.

Comment: If you have spaces in your folder names you probably want to surround them with quotes.

Comment: One thing I could see tripping you up with that particular path is that there is a space in the "Teddy Kim" folder. Try this:
`cd /c/Users/Teddy\ Kim/; mkdir hello`

Comment: You can either surround the space part of the path with quotes (as @marblewraith pointed out), or escape the spaces with `\ `

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink Thank you so much. That worked. Sorry, this is just so hard to get into as a beginner with a million different answers online. Appreciate you working with me here

Comment: To be clear the original command you posted, with quotes would be: `cd /c/Users/'Teddy Kim'`. Quotes usually work in most instances but it's handy to know about escaping when you have to deal with edge cases. Also what you're learning is not really just git, it's terminal (mingwin = subset of bash for windows) + git.

Comment: `bash` (which is not Git, it's just something Git *uses*, that's generally useful, that you're using) comes from the Unix/Linux world, where spaces in file and directory names are a bad idea and therefore don't occur. So bash assumes that there are no spaces in your files' names (because that's obviously such a bad idea, you're not using *Windows* after all :-) ) and thus behaves badly with those file names. It's kind of a self-fulfilling prophecy, that spaces are bad so no one uses spaces so therefore spaces are bad. But on Windows, spaces *aren't* bad, and now you have a culture-clash.

Comment: All this is so confusing for a first timer. I have so many programs installed that I dont even know what any of them do like ubuntu, git, node.js, etc. Just so overwhelming for a novice. Is there any recommended resources where I can consult how all these work together? Like Linux, Ubuntu, git, github, etc

Comment: A starting point if you want to go way back to the very beginning: http://files.catwell.info/misc/mirror/the-unix-programming-environment-kernighan-pike.pdf

Comment: Ubuntu = linux distro (operating system), git = version control (tracks change in files), nodeJS = javascript runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you what you need to know. This is a user / permission issue, not a git issue.

According to your terminal you are in the root directory (that's what `/` means).

Therefore your user account doesn't have permissions to create stuff inside the root directory, which is typically not what most people want to do anyway (at least not in *nix based systems).

The best way to get around this is to navigate to your user accounts "home" directory (represented by `~`) where (typically) you have complete unrestricted privs, using the `cd ~` command.

Note the absolute path of this home directory in windows is usually `C:\Users\<user name>`

Answer (score -1):

/ symbol means your are in root directory
So,just go to your C:\Users<user name> and that will solve your problem

Comment: Same as existing (and accepted) answer, except that this is also bad advice.